# Robust standard error (HC3) using vcovHC(), coeftest for plm object

Tags: r, statistics, plm, standard-error

I want to estimate a fixed effect model and use a robust variance-covariance matrix with the HC3 small-sample adjustment.

For the model itself I use following lines of code:

```
require(plm)
require(sandwich)
require(lmtest)
require(car)
QSFE <- plm(log(SPREAD)~PERIOD, data = na.omit(QSREG), index = c("STOCKS", "TIME"), model = "within")
```

This works very fine, now to calculate the HC3 robust standard error, I use used the function `coeftest` with `vcovHC` in it.

```
coeftest(x = QSFE, vcov = vcovHC(QSFE, type = "HC3", method = "arellano"))
```

And this does not work. The returned error goes as follows:

```
Error in 1 - diaghat : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The issue is in vcovHC: when one sets the type to `"HC3"`. It uses the function `hatvalues()` to calculate `"diaghat"`, which does not support `plm` objects and returns the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("hatvalues") : 
no applicable method for 'hatvalues' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"
```

Does anyone know, how to use the HC3 (HC2) estimator for plm. I think it should depend on the function hatvalues used in vcov, since HC0/HC1 works fine, because this do not need it.

Comment: A similar example works for me. It seems like `vcovHC` does not dispatch to the method supplied by `plm` for plm objects as there is no function `hatvalues` in plm, the word hatvalues is not even in plm's source code. Be sure to have package `plm` loaded when you execute `coeftest`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. hatvalues is meant to be in vcovHC() (see https://rdrr.io/cran/sandwich/src/R/vcovHC.R). I think my problem could also be in the variable PERIOD, it is a factor with 3 levels.

Comment: Be sure to have the latest version of plm installed from CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method supplied by `plm` for plm objects, there is no function `hatvalues` in package `plm`, the word "hatvalues" is not even in plm's source code. Be sure to have package `plm` loaded when you execute `coeftest`. Also, be sure to have the latest version of plm installed from CRAN (currently, version 2.2-3).

If you have package `plm` loaded, the code should work. It does with a toy example on my machine. To be sure, you may want to force the use of `vcovHC` as supplied by `plm`:

Fist, try `vcovHC(QSFE, type = "HC3", method = "arellano")`. If that gives the same error, try `plm::vcovHC(QSFE, type = "HC3", method = "arellano")`.

Next, please try:
`coeftest(QSFE, vcov.=function(x) vcovHC(QSFE, method="arellano", type="HC3"))`

**Edit**:
Using the data set supplied, it is clear that dispatching to `vcovHC.plm` works correctly. Package `sandwich` is not involved here. The root cause is the memory demand of the function `vcovHC.plm` with the argument `type` set to `"HC3"` (and others). This also explains your comment about the function working for a subset of the data.

**Edit2**:
Memory demand of `vcovHC.plm`'s small sample adjustments is significantly lower from plm version 2.4-0 onwards (internal function `dhat` optimized) and the error does not happen anymore.

```
vcovHC(QSFE, type = "HC3", method = "arellano")
Error in 1 - diaghat : non-numeric argument to binary operator
Called from: omega(uhat, diaghat, df, G)
Browse[1]> diaghat
[1] "Error : cannot allocate vector of size 59.7 Gb\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError: cannot allocate vector of size 59.7 Gb>
```

Comment: I updated the plm package, it still does not work for my whole sample. I tried with a smaller one. with only a smaller subset, it works very fine, but not with the whole. I appreciate your help, I will try to improve the quality of the whole data set and run it again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried also this approach. But it won't work. My data sample includes 288 individuals and 312 observations per individual. The code works well for max 148 individuals. including more than 148 stocks, causes the mentioned problems

Comment: Do you have a chance to make the full data available somewhere?

Comment: You can find it on https://github.com/dpendi/data/blob/master/STOFDAT.csv

Comment: Thank you. Please see the edit to my answer. Memory demands are too high, at least too high to handle for my machine

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Since I am supposed to use all the data, I found the function lm_robust() from package: estimatr. This one is able to use fixed effects, and estimates the same coefficients. The only thing I do not believe of the output are the standard errors, with HC3. Since using coeftest with HC1 increases the standarderror quite a lot. HC3 should be more restrictive. Using lm_robust does not. Using HC3 in lm_robust, gives only small changes in the standard error. But this is probably supposed to be in an other question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

plm developer here. While the efficiency issue is interesting computationally, from a statistical viewpoint these small-sample corrections are not needed when you have a 300 x 300 panel. You can happily go with HC0 (or if you definitely want a panel small-sample correction `"sss"` (panel DF) would be best anyway, and the latter is computationally much lighter).

The fact that small-sample corrections become useless when the data size increases is the main reason we did not allocate scarce developer time into making them more efficient.
Also, from a statistical viewpoint please be aware that the properties of "clustering" vcovs like White-Arellano are less than ideal for T ~ N, they are meant for N >> T.

Lastly, one clarification re: your original post: while originally `vcovHC` is a generic function in the 'sandwich' package, in a panel context the specialized method `vcovHC.plm` from the 'plm' package is applied.
Better explanation here: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v082i03

Comment: Thank you for your response; I have just a small question regarding vcovHC.plm from 'plm' package. Since vcovHC.plm uses vcovG from the plm package, the whole hat matrix is calculated with the function ```dhat``` in vcovG. I am referring to https://rdrr.io/cran/plm/src/R/tool_vcovG.R . Would it not be more efficient not to calculate the whole matrix (which in my opinion leads to my error) and instead just calculate the diagonal, that is needed for HC2 and HC3

Comment: Thanks for the observation, looks sensible. Will have a look.

Comment: I changed now with trace(plm:::vcovG.plm, edit = TRUE) the dhat function to: ```dhat <- function(X){
     
    S1 <- X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X)
     diaghat <- rowSums(S1 * X)
     return(diaghat)
  }``` . Now it works very fine; Thank you Helix and Giovanni for your help!

Comment: An implementation using this optimization is in plm version >= 2.4-0 so memory demand is significantly lower.

Comment: @GiovanniMillo, I also have a question concerning your paper cited in the answer. Would you mind to take a look? I did not see this thread so posted the question on [https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/589113/70093](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/589113/70093). In short: why some heteroscedasticity robust standard errors are in fact less than those in benchmark OLS.